# Visual Studio 2010 Pro: Error when creating project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

For whatever reason this error comes up when making a project, even though this is an error I expect to see at runtime or when there is a null variable.  All that visual studio creates in the project solution is a reference folder.

I've installed Visual Studio 2010 Pro from an Image file on a disk and I've reinstalled/repaired both VS and the Service Pack 1.

Is this just a known error?  Should I be concerned about running the program correctly?  It is especially important that I have all the libraries/content folders since I'm going to be using XNA to develop an Xbox game.

Sorry can't post pictures yet.

```
A problem was encountered creating the subproject "WindowsGame1". Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: you have already read the other answers, like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349460/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object

Comment: I had that when I screwed up my XNA & Kinect SDK installation. Then I installed VS2012, saw XNA was dead, and stopped using it haha

Comment: Oh I thought XNA would be a good tool but if a 3D game for xbox is doable without it I also have VS2012.  :)

Comment: And in response to you Dmi7ry, a lot of those errors of other people are during debug/running the program while this is definitely an installation error.  Thanks to both of you though.

Comment: I also have previous versions like 2008 redistributable maybe I should get rid of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error, which is somewhat along the lines of reinstall/repair.

Basically, I have windows phone sdk installed and I repaired it, somehow fixing my xbox/windows games.

Thanks for leading me to other solutions though, if anyone still has this problem I'd recommend reinstalling/repairing visual studio, sdk, frameworks 4.5, etc. the problem is bound to be an installation error.

Plus, I had to uninstall old 2008 or stand-alone visual c#, c++ IDEs.